# Google Drive files and folders

Tags: google-drive

Recently, my Google Drive has been terribly messed up and I don't know if it has anything to do with installing the Google Drive for Desktop or not.

1. My list of files and folders aren't alphabetized, whether I click on "My Drive" or "Recent".
2. The header for my Drive ("Title Owner", "Last Modified") etc) superimposes itself on top of the first couple of files or folders in the list and I can't access those files.  It seems the only way to correct this is to log out of Drive and back in, but that doesn't always work.
3. One Word doc I had saved (it's a table in Word) now has the column headers running vertically with the print running vertically (all in a vertical column instead of a row).  Does Google not support this kind of doc now or what?
4. Some of my files are just plain gone.  I found a couple of them in the trash bin but there is still one I can find but it shows an update date of 3-20-13.  It's a file I use at least once a week, so now all my edits since 3-20-13 aren't there!  What's up with that?

I am going nuts with Google Drive and am about ready to forget the cloud and go back to using my flash drive!! I have the free Google account, not the business one so I can't talk to them about it.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and opening google drive again. Or try a hard hard reload.Press ctrl+F5 a couple of times . That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the upper right, above your list of files, is a drop-down menu labeled "Sort". Your options are

   - Last edited by me
   - Last modified
   - Last opened by me
   - Title
   - Quota used

   Change to "Title" and you should be fine.
2. What browser are you using? Try a different browser or changing the size of your browser window.
3. Conversions of Word documents can be problematic. A formatting issue that Word will automatically fix for you may flummox Google Docs (and other conversion tools).
4. Search. Sometimes files are set to not appear in the "My Drive" view. Alternatively, click on the "Recent" option in the left-side menu.

Comment: I did find the "Sort" when I logged in using Chrome browser.  I've used the "Search" function to try to find the updated Excel file I am now missing and all I can find is the old Excel file dated 3-20-13.  I've tried the "Recent" and all the other choices in the left side and all I find is my old file.  Any other ideas, please?????

Comment: Search by file type. If it doesn't find your file then it's not there. Have you removed it from the Google Drive folder on your PC?

Comment: The old dated file is in my Google Drive folder on my PC too....this is really, really exasperating!  Why would this happen?  And how?

Comment: Is it in your Trash? (Left side, open "More" menu, click "Trash".) If it's not there, then I'm afraid it's gone.

Comment: Nope, not in Trash.  I have shares many of my files with my associate and I even looked in his Google Drive and it's the same, older dated file.  I've always checked to be sure my file is "saving" so I don't understand why it would revert back to a date 6 months previous.

Comment: It's entirely possible that your associate (or anyone you've shared the file with) moved the file out of the Google Drive folder. I'm afraid I have no further suggestions for you.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help!  Thanks, Al....